# Sharing a global object across files with circular dependencies

Tags: python, python-import

I have a global object which uses a class, and that class uses the global object. How can i put the imports correct in a clean way

I now have:

run.py (The file i run)

```
from global_class import Global_class
global_object = Global_class()
global_object.create_some_object()
```

global_class.py

```
from some_class import Some_class
class Global_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'my_name'

    def create_some_object(self):
        self.some_object = Some_class()
```

some_class.py

```
class Some_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print(global_object.name)
```

How can i now access global_object in Some_class? If i put:

```
from run import global_object
```

It creates a circular dependency, and it crashes. A possible method i thought of was putting the some_class import in the Global_class::create_some_object() method, but it seems to me as unclean code. Is there any better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any python `import module` or `from module import Class` statement runs corresponding module line by line and loads all the objects in the module namespace in the memory. However each of the names in the modules reside separately (that is the purpose of the modules after all). So a `global_object` in `some_class.py` is completely separate from the `global_object` in `run.py`. When the interpreter sees this name in some_class.py it will look in the local and global namespace (using the LEGB rule which stands for local, enclosed, global and builtins). But there is no reference to `global_object` exists here, it does in the *calling* module. Your suggestion of putting the `some_class` import statement inside the method `create_object()` will also not work for the same reason. As you have found out you cannot import `global_object` in `some_class` as it will again need to run the `run.py` thus creating a loop.

If you want to maintain this setup then one option would be to explicitly pass the `global_object` which is `self` in `Global_class` to the `Some_class()` constructor like below

```
#run.py                                                              
from global_class import Global_class
global_object = Global_class()
global_object.create_some_object()

#global_class.py
from some_class import Some_class
class Global_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'my_name'

    def create_some_object(self):
        self.some_object = Some_class(self) #self -> global_object

#some_class.py
class Some_class:
    def __init__(self, global_object):
        print(global_object.name)

$ python run.py 
my_name
```